# Questionable request to /user/soapCaller.bs

Tags: webserver, network-scanners

My webserver logs revealed a request to /user/soapCaller.bs from 220.226.188.32, which maps to Mumbai, India.  The HTTP user agent is called 'Morpheus ******* Scanner'.  My server returned a 404 error.

Obviously it is some kind of scanner, but I don't know any details.  Is it searching for vulnerabilities?  Does anyone have any information on this, and is it something to be worried about?

Comment: Check out "Morfeus" scanners or "soapCaller.bs" scans. They target PHP based sites...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the internet is a bad place. You have probably been scanned a thousand times before without noticing it,  everyone has.  There are bots that scan absolutely everyone for a handful of vulnerabilities in the chance of getting lucky.

Nothing special.

Answer (score 2):

This hit a couple of my boxes over December 2012 and today. http://pastie.org/5611554

Boxes get scanned all the time, what is interesting about this is why it is only requesting '/user/soapCaller.bs'. What is it looking for? (rhetorical question)

Also hit:

Nov 2008: http://www.rejetto.com/forum/hfs-~-http-file-server/did-anyone-know-anything-about-morfeus-fucking-scanner/

Dec 2011: https://serverfault.com/questions/337450/how-are-these-bad-bots-finding-my-closed-webserver